# Election result

Tags: support, election

The moderator elections are over, I think. Or is the election running still? 
Where do I find results?

Edit:

I concluded the election is over because David Zaslavski kills 
questions again using his special kind of "reasoning".

Comment: Well, but that conclusion doesn't follow because there was a week or so after the election ended when I wasn't really doing much ;-) In any case, if you object to the closing of a question you should comment on the question, or bring it up in the chat room.

Answer (score 4):

The *are* over, and you find the results at the [election page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election). There was also a [more detailed, but unofficial breakdown](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=832787#832787) posted to chat.

Comment: Thank You, dmckee, I visit meta onlx sporadic, so the results evaded me :=)

Comment: Yeah, it took a while for the results to show up on the site. Good to know that has finally happened.